Shorted left and right audio center pins and shields on AUX input
I'm a little bit of a beginner when it comes to this so I wanted to ask here to get some insight from people who know more and have more experience with the topic. I would like to apologize beforehand if the terms I use are incorrect as my knowledge in this topic is pretty bad.
So recently I changed the head unit of my vehicle in order to upgrade but I wanted to retain the functionality of the stock connectors such as the USB and AUX input. My main problem currently is with the wiring in order to retain the AUX input as the new head unit only has RCA cables to plug into. Based on this, my plan was to splice a right and left audio connector into the AUX input's left and right audio channels but then I encountered some problems. I measured with a multimeter that unless the 3.5mm socket was plugged, then both left and right audio channels were shorted to their shield and to each other.
Based on this, I was wondering if what I originally planned to do would somehow damage the connector or the audio output device or if I could freely splice the audio connectors and just play music as normal through the AUX input.
EDIT: I added some pictures where the aux input is shown, and these connect directly to a proprietary connector. To answer the question of one of the comments, the RCA cables themselves don't relate to the socket, it's that the head unit uses these cables in order to reproduce audio and video by connecting something to them. However, my goal is to keep the existing 3.5mm socket and use this very same socket to send audio to the head unit through my phone using a 3.5mm jack to jack cable.





how do the RCA cables relate to the 3.5 mm socket ... it is unclear what you are describing ... please add a diagram

You can buy 3.5mm jack to RCA plug adapters. Why are you splicing cables? But for your question, so you have RCA input and you are converting it to 3.5mm TRS input, but your 3.5mm TRS socket has swithes that connect the audio signals from Tip and Ring to ground Sleeve if there is no plug attached? And you are asking if this shorting may damage the head unit or audio source  e.g. your phone ?

You can buy a 3.5mm jack to RCA cable that already has the necessary circuitry to manage the shorting issue. Some cables come with built-in resistors or switches to isolate the channels when the 3.5mm jack is not connected.

Hi sorry for the late reply, what I meant was that when I measured with a multimeter when the aux input in the vehicle has nothing plugged into it, it shorts both left and right lines to their respective sleeves and to each other. The problem is that this aux input is proprietary from the vehicle's brand, which is why I'm looking into splicing the ends of a left and right RCA jack into the harness that came with the head unit. I was hoping to be able to connect my phone through a 3.5mm jack to jack cable to the aux input.

@Justme yes that would pretty much be it. From the picture I uploaded, the 3.5mm socket is soldered to some pins and it's from these that I took my measurements from so I'm not sure if the suggestion of using an adapter would work.
